# node-forge library crl distribution list comes as incorrect

Tags: node.js

I am trying below code in nodejs using node-forge library.

```
const cert = fs.readFileSync("test.cer")
const cCert = pki.certificateFromPem(cert)

const basicConstraints= cCert.extensions.find(item => item.name === 'basicConstraints')
console.log(basicConstraints.value);
```

output is :

```
0z0$\u0006\b+\u0006\u0001\u0005\u0005\u00070\u0001\u0018http://ocsp.digicert.com0R\u0006\b+\u0006\u0001\u0005\u0005\u00070\u0002Fhttp://...digiCA.crt
```

how can I convert into proper value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the extension value using `asn1.fromDer` and traverse the tree to collect CRL distribution points:

```
const pki = require('node-forge').pki;
const asn1 = require('node-forge').asn1;
const fs = require('fs');

const cert = fs.readFileSync("test.cer");
const cCert = pki.certificateFromPem(cert);

const distributionPoints = [];
const getDistributionPoints = (node) => {
  if (typeof node === 'string') {
    distributionPoints.push(node);
    return;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    node.forEach(getDistributionPoints);
    return;
  }
  if (node && typeof node === 'object') {
    getDistributionPoints(node.value)
  }
}

const ext = cCert.getExtension('cRLDistributionPoints');
getDistributionPoints(asn1.fromDer(ext.value))

console.log(distributionPoints);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @antonku. Your solution works very well. If you can write in a couple of line what asn1  does then it will be great. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @dhirajkumar Happy to hear that it worked well for you! As for `asn1.fromDer` - this method parses the DER byte buffer into ASN.1 object which we can traverse to collect distribution points.

Comment: if you have some time, may I ask another question: how do we know that the particular data was a DER byte. I am trying to parse a .crl file downloaded. but couldn't understand how to parse it to get revoked list of certificates.

Comment: @dhirajkumar So I didn't know that it was DER byte buffer in first place, I just assumed that it is when I saw it in the raw state. As for CRL parsing, I suggest that you open a separate question for it providing as much details as possible. I'll try to take a look at it when I have time. Also probably other people will answer it.

Comment: sure, I will do that. Thanks a lot for your help.